# Firefox: Any way to specify white or black lists for the history tracker?

Tags: firefox-extensions, history, firefox

I use Firefox very intensively, and from time to time I clear the browser history. But unfortunately the history is being filled very fast and it always keeps the history I'm not interested in:

- Some sites does not make any interest for me at all, and I would like never include them to the history tracker.
- Other web applications, like Google Reader, use #-links to navigate through the application content, and e.g. for Google Reader the old URLs simply become obsolete because I use "Mark as read". So I don't even see any reason of tracking the #-links in history.

Is there any way/extension/etc to support the features to support either white-lists or black-lists, or particular URL tracking for Firefox? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HistoryBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/historyblock/) Add-on for Firefox is what you're looking for:

> **About this Add-on**
>
> This tool will allow the user to specify a list of hosts to be blocked
>   from the history tab, the recently closed tabs list, and the download
>   manager.

You can easily specify a blacklist, and have all the other websites show up on your history.

Comment: Not really. E.g., I don't want to block "google.com/reader/view/", but I'd like to block "www.google.com/reader/view/#stream/user%2F...%2Flabel%2F..." because it contains a "#". HistoryBlock can work with domains only.

Comment: Well, there was an add-on like HistoryBlock which allowed Regular expressions, so you could match Google Reader URLs that contain `#` with a regex like `www.google.com/reader.*#.*`, but unfortunately it looks like this add-on does not exist anymore.

Comment: Yes, that would be exactly what I want. By the way, do you happen to know the name of the extension? (Perhaps I could be lucky to find it somewhere rather than the official repository)

Comment: Yes, the name is "No History" ([source](http://www.survivalistboards.com/showthread.php?t=146767)).

Comment: I think I found what you want: [Form History Control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/form-history-control/). It has more features than you need, but it looks like you can use regex to automatically delete certain URLs from your history: `This extension enables you to selectively delete privacy sensitive information without having to delete the entire history. With the help of powerful regular expressions, information can simply and effectively be retrieved, edited or deleted.`. I haven't tried it though.

Comment: Does the `Form History Control` add-on do everything you need? If it is what you were looking for, I'll edit my answer to include it.

Comment: According to the screenshots of the add-on, there is no need of doing this, because it stores the form data history, and not the browsing history. But I guess it's another add-on to appear in my extensions set. ;)